# How to use If .eof OR .bof condition in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

I am converting vb6 application into vb.net and in it .eof and .bof are used as condition. I am not understanding how to carry out these conditions in vb.net

```
sSql = "Select * From SPCsetup"
    Set dbConn = New ADODB.Connection
    Call openDBconn(dbConn)
    Set rsConn = dbConn.Execute(sSql)
If rsConn.EOF Or rsConn.BOF Then
            bFlag = False
        Else
            bFlag = True
        End If
```

Comment: Maybe if you could explain what that code is supposed be achieving, we could describe the best way to achieve it in VB.NET. It looks like you are traversing a Recordset. If you are migrating data access code, are you trying to use the VB6 code as close to as is as possible or are you writing new ADO.NET code? Whatever you're doing, ALWAYS provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I am writing a new code and I have updated question please check it out

Comment: I still don't really know what `rsConn` is and am just guessing that it is a Recordset. I think that you need to review your understanding of what "FULL and CLEAR" means. If you're writing new code then what you have there is irrelevant because you will be using ADO.NET in VB.NET or perhaps even Entity Framework. You should learn how data access works in VB.NET and then write the best code you can to implement your requirements. If you run into an actual issue doing that, then would be the time to post a question about that issue.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I am new to vb.net so I don't know much about it and yes rsConn is a recordset and it stores the values from query. What I am not getting is what does this result out **if(rsconn.eof and rsconn.bof )** and is there a way to do this in vb.net and how do i carry it out

Comment: `If rsConn.EOF Or rsConn.BOF =>` this means: *If no records are returned, then `bFlag = False` otherwise `bFlag = True`*. You could use a `SELECT COUNT` query, evaluating the result of an [`ExecuteScalar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executescalar) command. See the Docs [OleDbCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand) and [OleDbConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection) in general.

Comment: It you have VB6 code you don't understand, asking what it does to understand the logic makes sense. But trying to convert code line-by-line is not a productive approach; .NET features often work very differently than VB6 features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first off, ADODB is a COM component so you could in theory just keep on using it.  But it’s not really recommended as while it does have some beers and whistles they are not without their own problems.  Ado.Net exist for a reason and it’s not just because they like writing new code to do the same thing.

Secondly if you use a datareader then bof (before first record) is somewhat relevant, but if you use a dataadapter to fill a table it’s not.  It either has records or it doesn’t. If you want/need to continue using something like a record set, then that would be a datreader...there isn’t a BOF, but you don’t really need it. You find out nothing was returned, by the fact that nothing was returned.

```
sSql = "Select * From SPCsetup"
Using dbConn = New SqlConnection(connctionString)
    dbConn.Open() 
    Using dbCmd = dbConn.CreateCommand()
      dbCmd.CommandText = sSql
      Using dbReader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader
         bFlag = false
         While dbReader.Read
          bFlag = true
          'Do something 
         End While
      End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted from your other posts, you can (and should) do one of two things:

Create your own recordset class. It will take likely less then 30 minutes. You can then use your existing code with VERY little changes.

And you ALSO really (but really really) needed to share with everyone here WHAT KIND of data object you going to use, or are planning to use or are currently using in vb.net. (or ASK what kind of data object you should use).

Are you using a dataset?
Are you using a datatable?
Are you using a iList?

.net has a GAZZILLION choices, ranging from “iList”, and a bunch more I NOT listed out here. So we have little clue as to WHAT you currently using.

I am going to take a BIG FAT WILD guess and assume datatable.

Assuming we using a datatable, then you code would be something like:

```
Dim tblHotels As New DataTable
Dim strSQL As string = "select * from tblHotels"
Dim DataReader As New SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, My.Settings.SQLCon1string)
DataReader.Fill(tblHotels)

If tblHotels.Rows.Count = 0 Then
   bFlag = False
Else
   bFlag = True
End if
```

So, in place of

```
If tblHotels.EOF  then
```

You would then have:

```
 If tblHotels.Rows.Count = 0 Then
```

Comment: Ohk but what about .bof?